# I am trying google data transfer from azure datalake to GCS and was able to set it up.Could you please let me know why the transfer is very slow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-transfer

[Google data transfer details issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdN7q.jpg) 
I am trying google data transfer from azure datalake to GCS and was able to set it up.Could you please let me know why the transfer is very slow?

Comment: Google data transfer details issue is the screenshot

Comment: Are asking why the data transfer was aborted?

Comment: No the speed of the transfer is very low.Both Azure data lake and GCS are in EU regions.

Comment: Please look at the message. Status is **Aborted**. Speed does not matter until you solve that problem.

Comment: I have cancelled the transfer observing it is very slow